# There is no my.ini file in mysql5.6 installed folder

Tags: mysql, wamp, server

How to add that file. For this reason I can't run the mysql. There is a error called

> "ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once.
What my colleague did was, he copied the same file from his machine to mine and it worked !

P.S: I know its not a proper solution, but see if it works and saves some time for u

Comment: Can i download the my.ini file for mysql5.6? @saruchi arora

Comment: yepp sure try downloading for the same configuration if u find only .ini file online somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I heard In windows my.ini sometimes name as my.cnf

but find the my.ini/my.cnf file on your windows PC follow below steps.

goto services,find entry like 'MySQL55', right click on it ,select properties,you can see like "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" MySQL55